# Has there been a Starfleet ship class named for an actor before the Eisenberg class?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-discovery

The [Eisenberg Class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eisenberg_class) in Discovery Season 3 was obviously named for [Aron Eisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aron_Eisenberg) who was beloved by the Star Trek community.

Is that the only Star Trek ship class named for the actor, rather than the character?

Comment: Surely named for the inventor of the Eisenberg Compensator.

Comment: Ba-da-boom-tish.

Comment: Just a comment on trek history it wasn't until ST:II that another starfleet class was depicted on screen excluding the animated series.  And not until an episode of TNG did Constitution class get used in dialogue (it might have been in a prop diagram in the 1960s).  So this modern sense of Star Trek having so many ship classes they can be used to honor actors is a very recent one.  Rest in peace Mr. Eisenberg.  In the past usually a shuttlecraft was named in honor of someone involved in production and I'm not claiming that was a memorial for a deceased individual.

Comment: @lucasbachmann “this modern sense of Star Trek having so many ship classes… is a very recent one” — given that _The Next Generation_ debuted almost 35 years ago, I’mma have to quibble with your use of the term “very recent”.

Comment: (Back in those days we were all looking forward to a splashy new Batman movie and worrying about what Russia might do. It was a totally different world!)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite fair comment though I stand by the fact that there are not that many canonical classes even by the end of voyager.  And the high number that are canonical are largely kitbashes we can barely see.  Star Trek online classes don't particularly count to me and i strongly suspect thats where the sense of so many ship classes is coming from. (And as far as head canon goes I barely count voyager and nothing made later)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite of course there may be first generation trekkies that have Franz Joseph Starfleet Technical Manual classes in their head too which greatly expanded the pre TNG classes to be fascinated by.  So I'm not being critical of Star trek online but I still suspect that's a large source of beta canon class names.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite  Surely you mean the Heisenberg Compensator.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I do, and I don't, simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other objects in the Star Trek universe have been named after actors (see below), but this appears to be the first time a *class of ships* has been named after an actor on the show.

Things named after trek actors include;

- [The USS Yelchin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Yelchin), named after actor Anthony Yelchin.
- [Planet Royla (and the Roylan Star System)](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Royla), named after actor Deep Roy.
- [Nimoy's Star](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nimoy%27s_Star), named after actor Leonard Nimoy